# How to get the correct number of columns from mysql_fetch_array()?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here is a line of my code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

I want to get how many columns are in the row. I tried `count($row)` but this returned what I think is the number of cells for the whole $results.

i.e there are actually 7 columns, and 2 rows and `count($row)` returned 14. I want a function that will return 7.

Can you see where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - Answer found

Passed `MYSQL_NUM` as a second parameter to `mysql_fetch_array`.
Thanks anyway to everyone's answers.

Comment: You should accept John Kugelman's answer as he correctly described why you're seeing the results you are as well as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `mysql_fetch_array` each row has the columns indexed twice, once by column number and once by column name. So `count($row)` will be twice the number of columns.

Use `mysql_fetch_row` if you only want numerical indices, and `mysql_fetch_assoc` if you want name indices. These functions will both return rows with 7 entries.

Answer (score 5):

PHP has a function that returns the number of columns:

```
mysql_num_fields($result)
```

As the other answers say, you're getting double the count because `mysql_fetch_array()` returns both associative keys (by column name) and numeric keys. I'd use the above function instead though, regardless of what I'm using to fetch my rows.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns the row as a combined array of numeric indexes and associative keys. Which is why you get 14 instead of 7.

Use `mysql_fetch_row()` instead to get just the next row as a numeric index. Or `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get it with associative keys. Changing to either one will cause `count($row)` to return 7.

**Edit** I originally said `mysql_fetch_array()` returns the entire result. I have corrected this. The point still stands: using one of the other functions I mentioned will fix the issue.

Comment: That's not correct... mysql_fetch_array() will "Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both". It returns one row, but by default returns the columns indexed both by number as well as by column name, so each column is listed twice.

Comment: Will you forgive me if I upvote your edited answer and cause you to lose the coveted 1337-rep mark?

Comment: @BoltClock: LOL, no go ahead. I'll strive for 31337 :)

Comment: Sure, all is forgiven and I have changed my -1 to a +1 `:-)`